# componentWillMount method skipping a function call

Tags: reactjs

This is my componentWillMount - Method.

```
componentWillMount : function(){

  this.refreshFunction

  this.state.autorefresh = window.setInterval(
      this.refreshFunction
    ,30000);
}
```

This is mostly working as intended, but however, the first function call, so, the line "this.refreshFunction" is never being called at all.

The exact same function call in the interval later on works perfect.

Any ideas what is keeping React from executing it? I'm fairly new to React and don't have any idea how to track down the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try calling it correctly?

```
componentWillMount : function(){

  this.refreshFunction();

  this.state.autorefresh = window.setInterval(
      this.refreshFunction
    ,30000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working perfectly. I thought I have to leave out the brackets, because so far every call inside a React class seems to be done without.

Mind explaining me why I have to use brackets when I'm calling it outside of the Interval?

Comment: You only leave out the parenthesis when you pass a function as a reference. In order to run it, the parenthesis are needed.